# Dropping an item on an UserControl item in GridView doesnt trigger Drop event (includes sample project)

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, drag-and-drop

I want to be able to drag an item from a ListView, and drop it onto the a GridView that represents a list of UserControls.

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListView 
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            CanReorderItems="False" CanDragItems="True"
            DragItemsStarting="DragItemsStarting">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="280">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <Viewbox Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,20,0,0">
            <GridView x:Name="BoardGrid"
                       Width="600" Height="600">
                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="10"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:Name="GameBoardCellWithPieceDataTemplate">
                        <Grid Background="Green" Width="50" Height="50">
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
```

In the code behind I create the GridItems, set the AllowDrop property an assign an eventhander to the Drop event.

```
public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;

            this.DataContext = new List<string> { "Drag String 1", "Drag String 2" };
        }

        public void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (var row = 0; row < 5; row++)
            {
                for (var column = 0; column < 5; column++)
                {
                    var myUserControl = new MyUserControl { AllowDrop = true };
                    myUserControl.Drop += PieceDropped;

                    BoardGrid.Items.Add(myUserControl);
                }
            }
        }

        private void DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
        {
            var dragItem = (string)e.Items.FirstOrDefault();

            if (dragItem == null)
                return;

            e.Data.Properties.Add("dragItem", dragItem);
        }

        private void PieceDropped(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            object sourceItem;
            e.Data.Properties.TryGetValue("dragItem", out sourceItem);
            if (sourceItem == null)
                return;
            [...]
        }
```

The drag behaviour works fine, but when I drop an item of the ListView onto the GridView(Item), the Drop event isnt fired.

When I set the AllowDrop on the GridView itself, the Drop event is fired. Or when I wrap the UserControl in a GridViewItem, and set the AllowDrop on the GridViewItem, also the Drop event is fired, but after that i'm having problems with the DataTemplateSelecdtor I use.

Any clue?

I have created a sample project (http://sdrv.ms/V2OpfE) to demonstrate the problem